# Ruby/Webdriver: Ending a test gracefully and closing the browser if element not found

Tags: ruby, selenium

This is what I'm currently using : which works... but I would like it to end the test immediately and close the browser if the element is not found.  If the element is found I'd like for it to continue on with the rest of the test.

```
        begin
        assert element_present?(:xpath, "//*[text() = 'Narrative Support Primary Signs & Symptoms gar']")
        @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[text() = 'Narrative Support Primary Signs & Symptoms gar']").click 
            rescue Exception => e
                puts e.message
                puts "Filter Not Found In List"


    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The API mentions [Driver#quit](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver#quit-instance_method) as something to "quit the browser". It seems that adding `@driver.quit` to your rescue would do what you want.

Comment: So the issue I have when I add Driver.quit - is that it does quit the browser but the proceeds to throw me a big ugly "cannot connect to session" error because the browser is closed and it's trying to execute the remainder of the test.

Comment: At that point could you not toss down an `exit` to stop the script? So stop the browser and stop the script with a non-zero error code with `@driver.quit` and `exit 1`.